# Is there a DNS/AD Service available on GCP?

Tags: dns, active-directory

Is there a DNS/AD Service available on GCP ?

We are setting up an Environment on GCP and want to know if there is any service available on GCP which can act as AD/DNS ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, DNS/AD service is available on GCP. Google is touching its Managed Service for Microsoft Active Directory as being supported by a multiple-region datacenter infrastructure. You can implement a completely new Active Directory domain on GCP.

Compute Engine instances are pre-configured to use Cloud DNS for name resolution. Managed Microsoft AD creates DNS peering between the authorized network and the VPC host AD domain and DNS, forwarding all requests for the AD domain namespace to the private DNS zone in the tenant project.

For more information, kindly use Public Documents link [1] to create seamless DNS integration with managed Microsoft AD and [2] for Managed Service for Microsoft Active Directory.

[1] [https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/seamless-dns#:~:text=Compute%20Engine%20instances%20are%20preconfigured%20to%20use%20Cloud%20DNS%20for%20name%20resolution.&text=Then%20Managed%20Microsoft%20AD%20creates,zone%20in%20the%20tenant%20project](https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad/docs/seamless-dns#:%7E:text=Compute%20Engine%20instances%20are%20preconfigured%20to%20use%20Cloud%20DNS%20for%20name%20resolution.&text=Then%20Managed%20Microsoft%20AD%20creates,zone%20in%20the%20tenant%20project).

[2] https://cloud.google.com/managed-microsoft-ad